# In Arm what order are parameters stored on the stack?

Tags: assembly, stack, arm

This is a homework question. I'm trying to call a function of the form `FOO(A,B,C,D,E,F)`. The first four parameters are in register `r0-r3`. The last two are in `r7` and `r6` (respectively) so they are backwards. How can I push the parameters onto the stack so they are in the correct order?

is it `STMFD sp! {r0-r3}` then `STMFD sp! {r7, r6, lr}`? I'm using a full descending stack.

Are the diagrams on [this site](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/stack.html) correct because when it does `STMFD r13!, {r4-r7}` shouldn't `r4` be where `r7` is if the lowest register gets stored first?

Comment: Can't you just swap to register values then stmfd r0-r3, r6,r7,lr ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I think that's just an artificial convention set by the homework. The ARM ABI (at least for iPhone) passes arguments in the order of r0,r1,r2,r3,[sp],[sp,4],[sp,8],... when there's no struct return. r6,r7 are just two generic persistent registers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ARM the order of the register list does not matter. It will always store starting from the lowest register (R0, R1, R2, ...) The following are all equivalent (if accepted by the assembler):

```
STMFD SP!, {R0-R3}
STMFD SP!, {R3, R2, R1, R0}
STMFD SP!, {R1-R2, R0, R3}
```

Comment: With a full descending stack, this means R0 will be at the highest address, R1 lower address, even R2 lower address etc? But only if they are pushed using one STMFD e.g. STMFD sp! {R0-R3} is different than doing
STMFD sp! {R0}
STMFD sp! {R1}
STMFD sp! {R2}
STMFD sp! {R3}

Comment: @quest4knoledge: No, R0 is always the lowest, regardless the addressing mode of STMxx. Read the ARM ARM if you're not sure, it contains the pseudocode how the LDMxx/STMxx are executed.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you meant by "It will always store starting from the lowest register" I thought you meant the lowest register would get stored first, then the second lowest goes next on the stack(thus being at a lower address). So the lowest register gets stored first in the sense it will be at the top of the stack (where the top of the stack is considered lower addresses)?

Comment: @quest4knoledge: Just the lowest address. Where is the top of the stack is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Kenny's got the right answer, I think.

I also found some documentation on the subject if you haven't got it already: [ARM describes the most common calling convention here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf). [This website](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0203j/Chdebdjg.html) also has details on calling between C and ASM (which in turn illustrates calling conventions).

Comment: you mean "ARM describes the most common ..."; for all credit IBM might lay claim to, ARM it isn't ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just try it?

```
unsigned int foo ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c,
unsigned int d, unsigned int e, unsigned int f )
{

    return(a+b+c+d+e-f);

}
```

with a somewhat current gcc gives

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
   4:   e080c002    add ip, r0, r2
   8:   e08c1003    add r1, ip, r3
   c:   e59d3000    ldr r3, [sp]
  10:   e59d2004    ldr r2, [sp, #4]
  14:   e0810003    add r0, r1, r3
  18:   e0620000    rsb r0, r2, r0
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

llvm gives:

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
   4:   e59d1000    ldr r1, [sp]
   8:   e0800002    add r0, r0, r2
   c:   e59d2004    ldr r2, [sp, #4]
  10:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
  14:   e0800001    add r0, r0, r1
  18:   e0400002    sub r0, r0, r2
  1c:   e1a0f00e    mov pc, lr
```

Since this is homework I will leave it up to you to figure out if you can use a single stm/push instruction with multiple registers (as mentioned on other answers you DO NOT control the order on the stack with multiple registers) or multiple stm/push instructions with one register per. (or figure out how to make a test program that shows you the answer)

Knowing the convention is good, but you can answer questions like these without a full reading of the convention, use a compiler or two, that follow the convention.  Basically dont assume you know everything about the convention from some disassembly, for example you have not told us if a,b,c,d,e,f are 64 bit integers, double floats, bytes, halfwords, words, etc.  How many things are on the stack would definitely be affected by that, but, in what order and whether or not you can use stm/push instructions with multiple registers to get it there is likely going to be consistent.

EDIT:

Yes, that web page is correct, you need to get and read the ARM ARM (well now there is a separate ARM ARM (ARM Architectural Reference Manual) for each family).  These have the instructions defined with pseudo code, etc.  In this case:

```
The registers are stored in sequence, the lowest-numbered register to the lowest
memory address (start_address), through to the highest-numbered register to the
highest memory address (end_address).
```

Comment: The problem with "ask the machine" is that you don't know whether there is a guarantee that the behavior of what you are using (be it a CPU, compiler, DLL or whatever) will match the behavior of the next version.  Especially when doing bleeding-edge development:  "we fixed that bug".

Answer (score 1):

The registers are transferred in the order lowest to highest, so R15 (if in the list) will always be transferred last. The lowest register also gets transferred to/from the lowest memory address.